# Send Notification of friend request in android application

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

In my application I needed to send friend request to selected user from list of users(Users registered on server side). Once user clicks on add as friend, that person should get notification with yes or no functionality. 
I am considering Google cloud messaging for that, but not getting exact idea about it.
I tried the tutorials but not getting about sending friend request.
So anyone please guide me how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and [this](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139) tutorial.

To send request you can create your own custom request to selected user(That user also have same application and have `GCM RegID` in your database) and on server side you can send notification to registerd user and on receiver side you need to create receiver for friend request.